# Why is this simple input code giving "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"?

Tags: python

```
print ('hello welcome, thanks for playing')
age = int(input('enter your age here please')
name = input('enter your name please')
```

Comment: you are missing a closing paren.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. In the future, please make a [mre] to help you figure out simple typos like this. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 1):

after

```
print('hello welcome, thanks for playing')
age = int(input('enter your age here please'))  # one more ')'
name = input('enter your name please')
```